How to define Bold style font weight in PowerPoint?
I have a rather simple but complex issue related with PowerPoint.
In the branding I've been handed, I need to use the Medium font weight for headings and strong characters, along with the Regular font weight for the body text. However, as it should be in PowerPoint, it chooses the Bold font weight that I have installed for any text selected with the Bold button/shortcut.
I wish to be able to define my Medium font as the preferred Bold shortcut. Not only it helps me be faster by pressing a single button, but because I have all these presentations and they are all desgigned with Regular and Medium font weights in Pitch.com. When I export them, they turn all my Medium weights to Bold.
I have tried uninstalling the Bold font (that from time to time I need to use indeed) and all weights that are not the Regular and Medium fonts, but PowerPoint still doesn't read the Medium as the 'bold' to select. It turns all my 'bold' characters to a faux bold.
I have also tried to build a presentation from scratch in PowerPoint but the need to manually select the font-weight for multiple texts in multiple slides is exhausting.
